# Excel - sumproduct for tiered pricing model

Tags: excel

I have below data set starting in A1:

```
start tier  end tier    price
1           5           5
6           7           4
8           10          3
11          111         2
112                     1
```

The usage is in D1 and is equal to 10. I want to calculate the value based on usage and decreasing price. I have got two sumproducts but having no luck.

First one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($D$1>A2:A6), ($D$1-B2:B6), C2:C6)
```

Second one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($D$1>{0,6,8,11,112}),--($D$1-{5,7,10,111,1000}),{5,-1,-1,-1,-1})
```

Both miscalculate.

I prefer the first one as no hard coding is involved.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT and LOOKUP:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,D1)),{1,6,8,11,112},{5,4,3,2,1}))
```

[image]

---

With the lookup table:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,D1)),A:A,C:C))
```

[image]

Comment: Brill it works with blanks as well. Do you now any formula without using if to calculate usage per tier? So for Row 2 would be 5, Row 3 2 etc...

Comment: @Kalenji why the aversion to IF?  It is the best for what you want. But if you insist `=(($D$4>=B2)*B2)+(($D$4<B2)*($D$4-A2+1))`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have made a mistake in the @paul's solution comment and the result should be 42 - if the usage is 10 then it divides into 5 * 5, 2 * 4 and 3 * 3.

If I'm right, you can try the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$1>=A2:A6)*((B2:B6-A2:A6)+1+($D$1-B2:B6<0)*($D$1-B2:B6))*C2:C6)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for that. Is there any excel function I can use to show the usage per tier. I mean for the first tier (from 1 to 5) it would be 5, for the second 2 etc..I try to avoid ifs

Comment: @Kalenji why avoid if: `=IF($D$4>=B2,B2,$D$4-A2+1)`

Comment: IF we assume that usage per tier is in Column E and total usage in D1 then should not be =IF($D$1>=B2,B2,$D$1-A2+1) in E2?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use `SUMPRODUCT` for this? `RANGELOOKUP` might be more suitable.

Given the data:

```
End Tier     Price
       0         5
       5         4
       7         3
      10         2
     111         1
```

You can find the price for a quantity (e.g. 18 units) using `=VLOOKUP(18,A2:B6,2,TRUE)`

Comment: @ paul, usage goes like this, first 5 at 5, then 2 at 4 and 2 at 3. So the total is 38.